# Copy and Paste Dynamic range and prevent repeating the action

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I've got now. I will adapt it for work to copy a range into a new worksheet within a workbook. 
I want to expand the macro so that it deletes the previous copy/paste when a new one is made. 
This is key, b/c my users will execute this macro repeatedly.

This is my first attempt at setting up this procedure.
The macro will execute smoothly.

CODE:

```
Sub DynamicRange()
    Dim Start As Range, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet3
    With ws
        Set Start = Range("A1")
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Start.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range(Start, ws.Cells(LastRow, "C")).Select
        ws.Range(Start, ws.Cells(LastRow, "C")).Copy
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "sheet3"
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
     End With
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Just clear out the sheet??

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This issue is now solved. I decided to use a call within my routine that does precisely what I want. All the above coded can be disregarded. Sorry, community for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add one more range variable that defines the range of the current data. Then just clear that range before continuing with the other code?